# Encode Carrierwave attachment to base64 in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, base64, carrierwave

I am using the Carrierwave gem to upload attachments to my model. I added elasticsearch with the mapper attachments plugin to allow for full text search of the attachments.

Carrierwave and elasticsearch work fine, but in order to get the full text search working I need to encode the attachment as base64.

I have followed this tutorial (http://rny.io/rails/elasticsearch/2013/08/05/full-text-search-for-attachments-with-rails-and-elasticsearch.html) but I assume there has been some changes to either Rails or Carrierwave as I can't get it to work. Specifically, when I am trying to encode the attachment as base64, I get the following Type error:

> no implicit conversion of CarrierWave::SanitizedFile into String

The error is in the following line of the model:

```
File.open(Base64.encode64(File.read(document.file)))
```

If I replace the path with a url to an actual file it works fine.

I have searched SO and the only relevant answer I can find gives me the same error: [Carrierwave encode file to base64 as process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826675/carrierwave-encode-file-to-base64-as-process)

I am a complete rails newbie and hopefully this is something that's obvious to everyone except me, but we're all beginners at first, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CarrierWave's `read` method returns the content of the file. So assuming `Document` is your model and `file` is your uploader attribute, this should work:

```
Base64.encode64(document.file.read)
```